# is it possible to get current frame number in android animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing an application in which i want to change the text-view after few frames load like first text-view will be default then after 4 frames load text view should change then again after 9 frames load text-view should change. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `selectDrawable(int idx)` method of `AnimationDrawable` class. For that You should create custom class which extends `AnimationDrawable` declares interface `OnFrameChangeListener` and raises an `onFrameChanged()` method when frame changed like this:

public class ExtendedAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable {

```
public interface OnFrameChangeListener {
    void onFrameChanged(int numOfFrame);
}

private OnFrameChangeListener mFrameChangeListener;

public ExtendedAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable aniDrawable) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aniDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
        this.addFrame(aniDrawable.getFrame(i), aniDrawable.getDuration(i));
    }
}

public void setFrameChangeListener(OnFrameChangeListener frameChangeListener) {
    this.mFrameChangeListener = frameChangeListener;
}

@Override
public boolean selectDrawable(int idx) {
    boolean result = super.selectDrawable(idx);

    if (mFrameChangeListener != null) {
        mFrameChangeListener.onFrameChanged(idx);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Than You can use it like this:

```
View v ;

...

v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);
ExtendedAnimationDrawable extendedAnimation = new ExtendedAnimationDrawable(
        (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.animation_list));
extendedAnimation.setFrameChangeListener(new ExtendedAnimationDrawable.OnFrameChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFrameChanged(int numOfFrame) {
        // do your magic here
        // for example
        if (numOfFrame == 4) {
           // change TextView #1
        }
        if (numOfFrame == 4 + 9) {
           // change TextView #2
        }
    }
});

int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(extendedAnimation);
} else {
    v.setBackground(extendedAnimation);
}

extendedAnimation.start();
```